# Change monitor settings (duplicate, extend, etc ...)

Tags: python, windows, winapi, multiple-monitors

*Context*

Hi, i'm writing a simple software for a shop to show some products on a monitor. He would like the monitor to turn on and off at certain times. I am using DDC/CI commands to shut the monitor off, and all is working well. The problem is, if I do a full shutdown, i then have to press the physical button on the monitor to turn it back on. If i set it to standby, it wakes up immediately as the laptop is still connected and sends a video output. I figured if I set the monitor to standby and the laptop settings to "only main screen", it stays off, and turns back on when i set it back to duplicate or extend.

*Question*

Is there a way to change these mirroring settings from python?
[screenshot of windows mirroring settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Qo4.png)

Comment: You can try [SetDisplayConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdisplayconfig). [The display control panel applet calls SetDisplayConfig to apply the setting that a user selected from the drop-down menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/setdisplayconfig-summary-and-scenarios#setdisplayconfig-scenarios).

Comment: As I said previously, you can use `SDC_APPLY|SDC_TOPOLOGY_CLONE` and `SDC_APPLY|SDC_TOPOLOGY_EXTEND` to [set clone and extend topology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdisplayconfig#parameters) respectively.

Comment: i'm having the same issue. could you share code that would do that please?